# How to call a jquery funcion with a css button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two JavaScript buttons called Hide and Show:

```
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
```

they work, but I would like to replace them with `CSS buttons` that I designed:

```
<button class="button button1" onclick="hide">Hide</button> 
<button class="button button1" onclick="show">Show</button>
```

My problem is **they don't call the jQuery function appropriately**, I am trying to call it with its id as follows:

```
<button class="button button1" onclick="hide">Hide</button> 
<button class="button button1" onclick="show">Show</button>
```

But when I try to use them they don't work, I would appreciate any suggestion to solve this situation, see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adolf33/d6q9qjko/42/) to explain better see the situation.

Comment: They don't have any id's, so why would they work? If you keep that structure you could try select them by their text, but it's not fool proof.

Comment: `onclick="hide"` doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can do `onclick="$(this).hide()"` or instead of this what every selector you want.

Comment: If you want to do it inline - do what @JoseRodrigues said.

Comment: Alternatively, you have just one `button`that is intuitively named for UI purposes.  Then apply the `.toggler()` jQuery method to said button, with the click event function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6q9qjko/45/)

HTML - aplly `()` to make it a function call

```
<button class="button button1" onclick="hide()">Hide</button>
<button class="button button1" onclick="show()">Show</button>
```

JS - create the functions

```
function hide() {
  $("#texto").hide();
}

function show() {
  $("#texto").show();
}
```

---

Or simply apply the classes to the current buttons with `id`s and call it a day since its already working:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6q9qjko/48/)

```
<button id="hide" class="button button1">Hide</button>
<button id="show" class="button button1">Show</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support, I finally was able to overcome this situation.

Answer (score 2):

An element can have multiple classes and one ID.

```
<button class="button button1" id="hide">Hide</button>  
<button class="button button1" id="show">Show</button>
```

Classes you can use for styling, the id is used in the jQuery functions. No problem combining both.

You see in your jQuery code how the ID's are used to bind events to clicks on them:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("#texto").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("#texto").show();
    });
});
```

The onclick keyword you are trying to add, however, is a **javascript** event keyword and it **will not** call the jQuery functions.

In your fiddle you are mixing jQuery and plain javascript and I would encourage you to be more consistent, especially when you are not entirely sure what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

use class selector like :

```
           $('.button').click(function (evt) {
                if ($(evt.currentTarget).html() == 'Hide') {
                    $("#texto").hide();
                } else if ($(evt.currentTarget).html() == 'Show') {
                    $("#texto").show();
                }
            });
```

tested https://jsfiddle.net/d6q9qjko/68/

Answer (score 0):

Give your buttons distinct ids, then use

```
$('#myButtonID').click(function () {
                doSomething();
            });
```

or with a class:

```
$('.myClass').click(function () {
                doSomething();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<button class="button button1" onclick="hide">Hide</button> 
<button class="button button1" onclick="show">Show</button>
```

Use the ids as before. Example:

```
<button class="button button1" id="hide">Hide</button> 
<button class="button button1" id="show">Show</button>
```

Comment: They will have the same id's as the other buttons.

Comment: Yes but the question specifically stated replacing the buttons